# What is purpose of Client secret if it is not used for Google SignIn in React Natvie (ios/android) app having Backend api? How is this secure?

Tags: react-native, google-oauth, passport.js, google-signin

I have react native app(lets say ABC) from where I am going Google sign in, I get the idToken and send it securely using Https to backend server, it then validates idToken and gets accessToken. But in this entire process clientSecret is not used anywhere. My Client Ids can be used by anyone, let's say app XYZ to access user data. How is this secure?

On the other hand in my react website and backend server where I was using passport, client secret was needed. Am I missing something here?

And if the process used in native app is secure, I can use same process in react website, i.e. get rid of passport strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Client ID is included in HTML served to browsers, as you point out it's not secure--nor is it intended to be. The Client ID simply identifies the app.

For [Web apps](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849) Authorized JavaScript origins are required, and for back end services Authorized redirect URIs are also necessary. Requests/responses are verified by Google's OAuth service using these settings.

HTTPS, which includes a signed certificate is required and helps ensure traffic originates from source hosted and served from your verified domain.

For sign-in responses typically use a signed JWT that can be securely verified on the back end (unless OAuth 2.0 or gapi is used).

Client Secret, should of course never be included in HTML served to a browser and should be kept only on a secure location, out of source control, and on the back end server.

Use of a nonce would also help you avoid replay attacks. See the
[state](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server) variable for pure server side apps, or Sign In With Google [nonce](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#nonce) attribute.